# @ModelAttribute show in Swagger like body

Tags: java, spring-mvc, swagger

I use `org.springdoc:springdoc-openapi-ui:1.6.9`

I have controller:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> getApplications(@ModelAttribute ApplicationFilter applicationFilter){return null;}
```

And have class param:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ApplicationFilter {

  @Parameter(name = "ids", required = true)
  private List<Long> ids;
}
```

I need ModelAttribute to be displayed as [parameter fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mvVvL.png) in Swagger.

But is real show in the form of [body](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LD8sd.png)

If add `@Schema(name = "This is  field")` over field - [result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MCSoY.png)

Please tell me. What do I need to do so that my @ModelAttribute is displayed as parameter fields?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution that suits me:

```
@GetMapping
public ResponseEntity<String> getApplications(@ParameterObject @ModelAttribute ApplicationFilter applicationFilter){return null;}
```

add annotation @ParameterObject

Answer (score 1):

Note that you also annotate your class with `@ParameterObject`, there is no need to to specify that annotation in controller's arguments.